# How do you have text next to a logo and keep the header on top?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

So I am trying to make the header part of my website and I had a few questions. Before I go into them I just want to say I am very new at this, so please do try and make it simple. Thanks. Ok so here they are:

1. I want to have my text hovering next to my logo as you see on any other website.
2. when you scroll down the header follows you so you don't have to scroll all the way up.

So here is the code i have for the first question, but i dont have nay for the second:

```css
header { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 5%; 
  background-color: #52bad5; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2C9AB7; 
  padding-top: 0px; 
  margin-top: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <header> <a href="">

    <img src="file_locatio_here" alt="" width="50" height="50">

    <h4 class="logo">LIGHT</h4>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
</body>
```

I hope that makes any sense at all.

Comment: And the stick position worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the logo next to the text, all you need is to add `display: flex` to the wrapper, as seen below.

To make the header stick to the top, all you need to do is add `position: sticky` to it.

I'd advise reading more about flexbox here:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [flexbox.help](https://flexbox.help/)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #52bad5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2C9AB7;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="wrapper">
    <img src="file_locatio_here" width="50" height="50">
    <h4 class="logo">LIGHT</h4>
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#hero">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```